# Find cosine of acute angles in a right triangle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, quadratics

[image]

If sides of a right triangle are in Geometric Progression, then find the cosines of acute angles of the triangle.

**[Answer]** $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$,$\sqrt\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$

**My work:**

Using Pythagoras Theorem, $a^{2}+a^{2}r^{2}=a^{2}r^{4}$

$1+r^{2}=r^{4}$

$r^{4}-r^{2}-1=0$

Using quadratic equation, $r^{2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4}}{2}$

(-) sign rejected because squre cannot be nagetive

so, $r^{2}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

In right triangle ABC,

$\cos(A)=\frac{ar}{ar^{2}}$=$\frac{1}{r}$=$\frac{1}{\sqrt\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$ after rationalization $\sqrt{\frac{2(1-\sqrt{5})}{(1+\sqrt{5})(1-\sqrt{5})}}$ negative in denominator

$\cos(C)=\frac{a}{ar^{2}}$=$\frac{1}{r^{2}}$=$\frac{1}{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$= $\frac{2(1-\sqrt{5})}{(1+\sqrt{5})(1-\sqrt{5})}$=$\frac{2(1-\sqrt{5})}{-4}$= $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$

I cannot understand what is wrong with my calculations. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cos=adjacent/hypotenuse.  (In fact both your expressions for cos are greater than $1$ and therefore obviously wrong.)

Comment: @David I've fixed it but still its not the required solution

Comment: maybe ${2 \over 1 + \sqrt 5} = {\sqrt 5 - 1 \over 2}.$ and the same for the second pair.

Comment: If you rationalize the denominators, you can get these to be the same. Your answers are correct, just in a different form.

Comment: I tried to rationalize cos(A), multiplied conjugate on both numerator and denominator

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1-\sqrt{5}}}=\sqrt{\frac{2(1-\sqrt{5})}{-4}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}}$

Comment: @BenjaminRoycraft it is correct for Cos(c) but it make (-) in underroot for cos(A)

Comment: @DheerajKumar take a look at my answer. The calculations can be very quickly justified by cross multiplying, and you will see that conjugates cancel out all of the squareroots

Comment: @BenjaminRoycraft (-) in under root in your fourth step it makes the equation highly unstable

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. However, at no point are the negatives under the square root imbalanced. There is always a negative in the numerator and the denominator. The total expression under the square root is always positive, then. Remember that $\sqrt{5} > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do have the right answers; they just merely look different. A quick check on wolfram alpha will tell you that they are equivalent.

First answer: http://cl.ly/image/1C3F0O3U1A16
[image]

Second answer: http://cl.ly/image/0E0X3z3q0M0B
[image]

Both of these calculations can be very quickly justified by multiplying both sides of the equation by the denominator and noticing that the conjugates cancel out all of the squareroots.

Comment: please show your step by step calculations for cos(A) I have found the correct solution for cos(C)

Comment: I didn't do any calculations of my own. All I did was take your answers and show that they are equal to the answers provided

Comment: all I am doing is simply showing you that you have been correct this whole time, and your teacher will probably count your original answer as correct since it is equivalent